# confused about the size of NodeJs executable file is only about 32MB

Tags: node.js

confused about the size of NodeJs executable file is only about 32MB, but it contains many deps, eg: v8, libuv and so on. if I compile v8 separately, the result is large, why???

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if I compile v8 separately, the result is large, why NodeJs executable file contains those but more smaller.

Comment: There can be dynamically linked libraries, different build options. What is the task you want to perform?